# Object doesn't support this property or method vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

The error occurs in here:

```
Application.Run "Macro2.Execute", param
...
```

*Execute* is a public sub i called from other Module "*Macro2*" installed in another template.

Upon run of the code:

IF there is NO open Word Document = **No error**

IF another instance of Word Document is open = **Stated error occurs.**

Is there any fix on this? :(

The whole code is below:

```
Dim objWord As Object

On Error Resume Next 'suppress error checking for the next instruction
 Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

 If objWord Is Nothing Then
    'no instance, so make a new one
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    bNewInstance = True
 End If
On Error GoTo 0 'resume error checking   

'Close Document1
ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges

' Open the global template
Set docAddIn = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\WordAPI\GlobalTemplate.dotm")
docAddIn.ActiveWindow.Visible = False

' Run the the public sub Execute from global template module "Macro2"
Application.Run "Macro2.Execute", param
```

Comment: without providing the code, there is no way we can help you...

Comment: What you are possibly missing is reference to another Template (name). Solution can look like this `Application.Run "'TemplateNameOrSomething'!Macro2.Execute, param`. You need to make some test of what to put in `TemplateNameOrSomething` on your own.

Comment: Hi KazimierzJawor, 
hmmmm... I've tried your suggestion before but it doesn't work in me. :(